# Retrieving saved information from saved local file when I re-open my app

Tags: android, file, save

I am trying to retrieve saved information after I come back to my android app.  I am not getting any errors but nothing is coming back into the app like it's supposed to.  Any suggestions as how to improve my code?

> package edu.rasmussen.mobile;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static String STORELOCATION="storelocation.txt";

private EditText txtEditor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatDegrees);
    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatMinutes);
    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatSeconds);
    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongDegrees);
    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongMinutes);
    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongSeconds);
}



public void saveClicked(View v){
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out=
            new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORELOCATION, 0));
        out.write(txtEditor.getText().toString());
        out.close();

        Toast.makeText(this,  "The contents are saved in the File.",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(),     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public void readFileInEditor()
{
    try
    {
        InputStream in = openFileInput(STORELOCATION);

        if (in != null)
        {
            Reader tmp = null;
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;
            StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                buf.append(str+"n");
            }
        in.close();
        txtEditor.setText(buf.toString());
        }
    }

catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e)
{

}

    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }
}

public void retrievedClicked(View v){
    try {
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("storelocation");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);


        Toast.makeText(this,  "The contents have been retreived.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    catch (IOException ioe)

    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

>

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText variable 'txtEditor' can only reference one EditText view. By assigning it to one view after another in onCreate(), it doesn't point to all of them, only the last one assigned. So it points to LongSeconds, which is the last assignment you make:

```
txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongSeconds);
```

Assuming that your save and retrieve code works, you are therefore only saving and retrieving the value for LongSeconds. To save the state of all your views, they will each need a distinct variable to reference them, for example:

```
txtEditorLatD = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatDegrees);
txtEditorLatM = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatMinutes);
txtEditorLatS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LatSeconds);
txtEditorLongD = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongDegrees);
txtEditorLongM = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongMinutes);
txtEditorLongS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LongSeconds);
```

When you save, you will need to write out the value of each one in turn with a separator character of some sort. Then when you read the data back in, split it by the separator and re-populate your views.

An easier approach to save/restore is to use SharedPreferences, which is a commonly used way to store the state of an activity (or any other data that you wish to persist). A SharedPreferences file holds key/value pairs. For example to save the string value of each EditText:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("LatDegrees", txtEditorLatD.getText().toString());
editor.putString("LatMinutes", txtEditorLatM.getText().toString());
//repeat for each view to be stored
editor.apply();
```

To retrieve that data:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
txtEditorLatD.setText(sp.getString("LatDegrees", ""));
txtEditorLatM.setText(sp.getString("LatMinutes", ""));
//repeat for each view to be restored
```

Comment: I've updated the code but now the Shared Preferences sp is giving me an error indicating the local variable is not used.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to prefix getString() with 'sp.' in my last 2 lines of code. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  It's working but only half the time as my UI crashes but you got me further.